# jQuery animations to take place after one another

Tags: jquery

I have the following slideshow im trying to build from scratch.

http://jsfiddle.net/FeqkB/

Basically I want each parent container to fade out and the next to fade in after 5 seconds. When the parent fades in, I then want the 'img' to animate 1 second into the parent element becoming visible.

I cant seem to find anything on google regarding how to do this, but would the 'queue' function in jQuery come into play here?

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: almost all animation functions have a 2nd parameter that gets called when the animation ends, so if you want a fadein after a fadeout ends you'd do something like .fadeIn(300, function() {$("#whatever").fadeOut(300)})  for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for .delay().

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Usage:

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the .queue method of jQuery?

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Fx Queues plugin: https://github.com/lucianopanaro/jQuery-FxQueues